# FileNotFoundError When Attempting to Open a File in the Same Directory

Tags: python-3.x

The `txt` file is saved in the exact same folder as my code but when I run it I get that traceback. I right clicked saved file directly to folder but when run the code vs studio. I am very new to code sorry for the basic question.

```
file = open('regex_sum_1114202.txt', 'r')
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\EM2750\Desktop\py4e\ex_11\ex_11.py", line 2, in <module>
    file = open('regex_sum_1114202.txt', 'r')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'regex_sum_1114202.txt'
```

[screen shot of traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPwON.png)

Comment: You are not in the same dir as your code. when you run your code from dir 1, you give the path to your code in dir2. but open will open files from your current dir, not from the dir your codes in. so in this case its looking for the file in dir1 and it doesnt exist there.

Comment: Please avoid pasting stacktrace as image, you should paste it as a formatted text (e.g. code, between tripple backquotes).

Comment: @Chris Doyle. Please explain how to how to run the code in the same dir. I'm still new and learning

Comment: So your in dir 1, but your code and file is in dir2. Either change to dir 2 and run the code, then you will be able to read the file as you will be in the correct dir. or in your code specify the full path to the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `file = open('./regex_sum_1114202.txt', 'r')` instead.

- This explicitly specifies that Python should look for the file in the current directory by providing the relative path. Think of the point as a shorthand for the current working directory. So if the current working directory is the directory where the script and the file is, that should work.
- Use forward slashes (`/`) instead of backslashes (`\`). Backslashes are the default directory separator on Windows, but here they make problems because they are interpreted as escape sequences by Python. Alternatively, you can use two backslashes after another as directory separator: `\\`.

You can also try to specify the full path before the filename: `file = open('c:/Users/EM2750/Desktop/py4e/ex_11/regex_sum_1114202.txt', 'r')`. The downside is of course that the path wouldn't be correct anymore if you'd move the file.

Comment: file = open('c:/Users/EM2750/Desktop/py4e/ex_11/regex_sum_1114202.txt', 'r') work's well thank you